# Doorbell Transformer

Tags: electrical, wiring, furnace, doorbell

Trying to install a nest doorbell but need to change the transformer. I believe I found it here but it is attached to a switch next to the furnace. When I unhooked the wires the doorbell stopped working so I believe this is it. Would like a second opinion?[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I'd be happy to give you a *third* opinion: electrical codes in some places indicate you shouldn't have anything else powered by your furnace circuit.

Answer (score 3):

That is definitely what you're looking for. To be safe,trace the wires as far as you can to make sure they're not connected to anything else too. That's a strange location for one, mounted on a box to a furnace. Determine if the switch controls the transformer, that would be strange too. Make sure it's not feeding your thermostat.

Comment: Yeah seems odd. I added some more pics to show what I’m working with.